# javascripts regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string  1,2,3,4,5

and say i remove 1 then it becomes ,2,3,4,5 or 1,2,,4,5

how do I remove "1," or any number from the list  and replace those extra commas and also keep in mind the last number "5" doesnt have a comma.

I can use the string replace javascript function , I am more concerned with the last number

example if i remove 5
it should show as 1,2,3,4

Comment: Wait - do you have a string or an array?

Comment: Looking at your comment on @webSol's answer, it sounds like you want a method to remove any given number from a comma-delimited string? If this is correct, please update your question accordingly. And clarify the whole "string or array" thing.

Comment: @jball: There is no comma-delimited string to be seen here. Consider `:foo:bar:`.  That has 2 fields if colon-delimited, 3 fields if colon-terminated, and 4 fields if colon-separated. We're programmers: don't get sloppy.

Comment: @jball that right  its a string

Comment: @tchrist, what?! Ref: [A delimiter is a sequence of one or more characters used to specify the boundary between separate, independent regions in plain text or other data streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter), particularly [field delimiters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Field_and_record_delimiters)

Comment: @jball, that's some stoopid Windoze daffynition.  My point stands: foo-terminated, foo-separated, and foo-delimited mean three completely different things, and understanding this distinction is critical if you expect to generate a correct field count in things like ":fee:foo:fum".  Ref: [delimiter: A character or string that sets bounds to an arbitrarily-sized textual object, not to be confused with a separator or terminator. "To delimit" really just means "to surround" or "to enclose" (like these parentheses are doing).](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#D)

Comment: @tchrist - 1) a Perl glossary defines terms for Perl, not for general usage. 2) "delimiter" is derived from "delimit", which has to do with marking boundaries, for example the boundaries between fields. Why are you acting so aggressively myopic?

Comment: @jball, it does not matter what the programming language is; the English is invariant. Consider `":fee:fie:foe:fum:"`. That has 4 fields if colon-delimited, 5 fields if colon-terminated, and 6 fields if colon-separated. This is a useful, important, and necessary distinction, one you lose by watering down the meaning of delimit to mean merely separate, which is a different thing all together.

Comment: @tchrist, You're the one fighting the understood meaning of the word in English. Where's an authoritative general (i.e. not specific to one programming dialect) dictionary that defines "delimit" in your terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
theString.replace(/«the number»,?|,«the number»$/, '')
```

```
>>> "1,2,3,4,5".replace(/1,?|,1$/, '')
"2,3,4,5"
>>> "1,2,3,4,5".replace(/2,?|,2$/, '')
"1,3,4,5"
>>> "1,2,3,4,5".replace(/5,?|,5$/, '')
"1,2,3,4"
```

Or treat the string as an array, with

```
theString.split(/,/).filter(function(x){return x!="«the number»";}).join(",")
```

```
>>> "1,2,3,4,5".split(/,/).filter(function(x){return x!="1";}).join(",")
"2,3,4,5"
>>> "1,2,3,4,5".split(/,/).filter(function(x){return x!="2";}).join(",")
"1,3,4,5"
>>> "1,2,3,4,5".split(/,/).filter(function(x){return x!="5";}).join(",")
"1,2,3,4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expression. Use arrays. You can `split()` your string into an array on the comma, then remove the elements as needed. You can then use `join()` to put them back together as a string.

Comment: +1 - though you should mention `join` to rebuild the string from the array

Comment: var str = '1,2,3,4,5';
str = str.replace('1,', ''); I am trying to remove any of the numbers but this fails when you try to replace "5" str = str.replace('5,', '');

Comment: @user244394 `str.replace` is not mentioned in this answer, and you are providing conflicting specifications in your question and subsequent comments.

Comment: I was trying couple thing split and replace

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeValue(value, commaDelimitedString)
{
    var items = commaDelimitedString.split(/,/);
    var idx = items.indexOf(value);
    if(idx!=-1) { items.splice(idx, 1); }
    return items.join(",");
}
```

Comment: +1 nice function. I guess not as pretty as **KennyTM** though ;)

Comment: @Jason McCreary, Thanks, though to be fair, I voted for KennyTM's as well :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use split and merge functions in javascript